Windows Drive Encryption when dual booting Debian 12 and Windows 10
I have a Thinkpad E14 multibooting Debian 12 and Windows 10 on nvme drive #1 and another Windows 10 on nvme drive #2.
Secure boot is enabled and the shimx64.efi bootloader set up to give a Grub menu of Debian as well as both Windows 10 OSs.
My question:
When booting in to Windows 10 via the Grub Menu bootloader I was seeing a yellow exclamation mark alongside the C: drive. I was seeing this with secure boot enabled AND disabled. This is related to bitlocker settings in Windows and drive encryption.
But I was NOT seeing the  yellow triangles when booting in to Windows 10 directly by selecting a Windows bootloader from the BIOS?
Debian talks about shimx64.efi being signed my Microsoft but I don't know if that is related or not?
In the Win 10 BitLocker Drive Encryption GUI it was saying that Bitlocker was OFF on all the system drives on each of my Windows 10 OSs.
According to this thread the yellow triangle means:

"Device Encryption is suspended.... while your files are encrypted the
encryption key is accessible. However, Device Encryption should be
disabled, since Ubuntu does not play well with it."

So I followed the suggestion also in that thread and disabled Bitlocker protection for the C: drive. Something I am confused about? When I went in to  the BitLocker GUI in win 10 it said it was NOT enabled but when I ran these commands:
manage-bde -status C:
manage-bde -off C:

I could see that files on the drive were encrypted.
After I ran the command to turn off encryption the Yellow triangle went away even I booted in to Windows 10 via Grub shimx64.efi bootloader. I think with Bitlocker there are two steps: encrypting the drive data and encrypting the encryption key?
In Summary:
What was I seeing here and did I do the right thing?
Maybe I'm misunderstanding how BitLocker works and maybe this was nothing to do with BitLocker?
With Secure boot on OR off... Why was there no yellow triangle when I booted in to Win 10 using a Windows bootloader but there was a yellow triangle when I booted in with the Debian grub shimx64.efi bootloader?
Maybe I have got some setting wrong in the Grub configuration?

I think with Bitlocker there are two steps: encrypting the drive data and encrypting the encryption key? No. I'm misunderstanding how BitLocker works and maybe this was nothing to do with BitLocker? The drive was encrypted with BitLocker and you were unaware it was encrypted.

Yes, I don't know why but looks like Windows suddenly turned on encryption by itself. Maybe after an update? I didn't turn it on. My main question is why the yellow triangle alongside the C: drive when I booted in with the Grub shimx64.efi bootloader but not when I was choosing a Windows bootloader from the BIOS?

From what I understand there are five states for bitlocker:

Off, no encryption is present
Encrypting, a drive is currently in the process of encrypting
Decrypting, a drive is currently being decrypted
Suspended. The drive is encrypted (or partially encrypted) but the encryption key is stored unencrypted on the bootloader partition. This is not a recommended state but is necessary temporary state for some actions such as BIOS updates.
Encrypted. The drive is fully encrypted and the key is protected. The bitlocker key is stored in TPM, remote network boot server, a USB drive, or a user's head. This is the normal bitlocker state.

I haven't messed with multi-OS boot but I would guess the recommended state is encrypting your Windows partition and using a separate partition for your Debian OS. However Bitlocker may not be happy with GRUB being the primary bootloader.
